# NASA live Europe imagery

Tags: astronomy

I saw here https://api.nasa.gov the NASA provides tons of public endpoints for browsing data/images. I'm just searching for a webservice that exposes live satellite (hourly updated) images on the Europe. I'm not clear if it's there is something like that or not.

Maybe you know some other webservices?

Comment: https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/viewer.html comes closest to this that I am aware of